# How can I stack bars manually with already counted splits using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, geom-bar

I have the following dataframe, and I am trying to use ggplot2 to make a stacked barplot split into "Early" and "Late". The column "Count" is the total count (Early+Late).

```
    Stage   Count   Early   Late
------------------------------------
    PreMBT  2208    1539    669
    Dome    2050    1507    543 
    Shield  1939    1442    479
    Bud     1865    1377    488
```

I want the Stage on the x axis, and Count on the y axis. However, I want to break up the bars by having Early be one color and Late be another color, with the legend having these 2 as well. I have tried many things but it is not working...which is why I was wondering if there's a manual way to separate it? Any help appreciated! This is what I have so far (which is not broken up by Early/Late yet):

```
densityplot <-ggplot(data, aes(x=Stage,fill=Stage,weight=Count))+geom_bar()
```

but when I try doing fill= Early, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I excluded `Count`:

```
mlt = melt(df, id = "Stage")
mlt

ggplot(mlt, aes(x=Stage, y = value, fill = variable))+
  geom_bar(position = "stack", stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much- this works just as I wanted it!

Comment: Just wondering- what exactly does the melt function do? And what does "value" refer to here? @AK88

Comment: `melt` just gives you a more suitable data structure and its widely used with `ggplot`. Have a look at package `reshape2`. `melt` gives 3 columns and value represents data for `Late` and `Early`